# JavaScript: How do i use a string as a piece of code

Tags: javascript, string, graph, equation

I am making a simple-ish graph maker to visualise equations. I need to be able to have the user input a string in a textbox and then interpret that as a piece of code I can execute to produce the graph. The way I am displaying the graph is by going through x in small increments and using an equation to then calculate the y position and then drawing a line between the points. At the moment I am just manually making a function in the code for example:

function(val) { return (val * val) + 5; }

but I need to be able to create a similar function from a string so the user could just input something like "(x*x)+(2*x)". is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why not use input boxes for each separate component of the equation? Like [this](http://inequalitycalculator.com/)

Comment: Ah yes thank you! I would also like to be able to use other functions though like sin, cos, tan etc. I could just use separate inputs for this but I just thought it would seem more flexible if I could just write out the equation in one text box.

Comment: Then I would consider some kind of parsing mechanism. Maybe make extensive use of the `split` function.

Answer (score 0):

Canonically, this is done with [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), although it comes with many caveats and should probably be avoided.

There are several questions on SO that discuss `eval` alternatives, but in your case, I would suggest a very bare-bones parser -- especially if all you're handling are mathematical equations.